# Access Session Variable in Laravel Custom Error Pages

Tags: php, laravel, session

I am trying to create a custom error page in Laravel 5.3. I wanted the retrieve some variable stored in the `Session` like `Session::get("username")`, however what I get is an empty variable.

How am I suppose to get any `Session` variable in a custom error page in Laravel or is it not possible?

Comment: Session::get("username") is used to access a session variable. But to cross check it, print all session values and check if the index is available or not

Comment: I used `dd(Session::all())` to dump all `Session` variable in the error page, but it's empty. I can access the variable just fine in non-error pages. All my `Session` variables are set during login.

Comment: On which error page did you try your `dd(Session::all())` ?

Comment: @BastienPhilippe It's a custom 404 error page, I wanted to print the username on one of the section in the page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Laravel did not find the route, you did not pass through the middleware `\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession` (which is by default in `web` middleware group), so your session is not started.

To have your session initialized, move `\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,` from `web` to `$middleware` in `Kernel.php`:

```
protected $middleware = [
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
],
```

Middlewares in `$midleware` are always run so your session will be initialized, even if the route is not found.

Comment: This worked! Is there any downside if the `session` is enabled for every single route in Laravel?