# 'Session store not set on request' after including header

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using the following exception handler in the handler.php file :

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    if ($e instanceof CustomException) {
        return response()->view('errors.404', [], 404);
    }

    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

It is working fine until I include the header to the `404.blade.php` file :

```
@include('includes.header')
```

I start receiving this error :

```
Session store not set on request. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\sharp\resources\views\includes\header.blade.php)
```

Comment: What is the content of your `includes.header` template? Are you accessing the session in that template?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Auth::user() for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the route wasn't found, the `web` middleware, which starts the session, was never applied.

I'm not a fan of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39952691/6472849), but it is relevant.

Instead, consider passing a parameter to your nested template specifying if the section of your template calling `Auth::user()` should be rendered, via the `@if` blade directive.

Something like:

```php
@include('includes.header', ['omit_auth' => true])
```

then in your header template:

```php
@if (!empty($omit_auth))
{{ Auth::user()->name }}
@endif
```